# Delete one Reducer data from store before Rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

I have an API call which gets the raw HTML, i need that HTML in the page, so i am making an call through redux action and get the data and want to paint in the isomorphic application.

But i don't want that HTML go as initial state when doing hydration. It is messing up the store on client side and UI. So is that anyway i can remove that state from store.

```
htrHtml = store.getState().HTMLData.htr;
ftrHtml = store.getState().HTMLData.ftr;
```

so once i get the html, I send that to template, but can i delete the HTMLdata from store here..

store, has three states here and i want to delete the HTMLdata...

```
const InitialView = (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <RoutingContext {...renderProps} />
        </Provider>
      );


  renderToString(<HtmlTemplate component={componentHTML} config={config} store={initialState} headerData={htrHtml }/>);
```

Comment: Have a look at `redux-persist`, it lets you white/blacklist reducers.

Comment: Thanks, let me check that.

Comment: You change the state via actions, so just create a `resetHTMLData()` action and dispatch it on the store before serializing it.

Comment: good idea, i will dispatch a dummy action which resets the data then.